# Serverless Framework - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless-framework

I'm facing with this issue of "JavaScript heap out of memory" when I  deploy or ru service with 'serverless offiline' command.

I'm using nestjs - a node framework - and building the project for node 10x.
On my terminal I got this below.

I found some fixes like

1. type " node --max-old-space-size=1024 index.js"  on terminal
2. use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit
3. append on script tag in package.json some like ""scripts": {
   "webpacker": "node --max_old_space_size=4096"
   not of theses works.

any clue?

```
PS D:\m1_workspace\dw-api> serverless offline
Serverless: Compiling with Typescript...
Serverless: Using local tsconfig.json

<--- Last few GCs --->
al[21864:000001EF81231660]    20688 ms: Mark-sweep 1394.2 (1429.4) -> 1392.3 (1429.9) MB, 977.1 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 62 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 987 ms) (average mu = 0.074, current mu = 0.010) all[21864:000001EF81231660]    21557 ms: Mark-sweep 1392.3 (1429.9) -> 1392.2 (1427.9) MB, 868.1 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 868 ms) (average mu = 0.037, current mu = 0.001) allo

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x002e2c61e6e9 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: splice(this=0x03a8c4a97e89 <JSArray[8]>,0x0237e40868f9 <TypeObject map = 000001453BA516C9>,0,8,0x03a8c4a97e89 <JSArray[8]>)

    1: getUnionType(aka getUnionType) [00000057B5C33821] [D:\m1_workspace\dw-api\node_modules\@hewmen\serverless-plugin-typescript\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:~34245] [pc=000003F28C0363E9](this=0x007f886026f1 <undefined>,types=0x010...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: What is your code doing when it runs out of memory?  Possibly a bunch of asynchronous operations all in flight at the same time?  Or reading large files into memory?  Or parsing large pieces of JSON?

Answer (score 7):

A quick workaround is to try to run below command first:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192
```

I have a large serverless project which ran into similar issue when I tried to deploy with "sls deply". And this workaround works for me.

Hope it can help.

Comment: while running, it shows, export is not recornized

Comment: If you are using this in a script then the following could be useful `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 npx sls package` (you can set the environment variable for just one command instead of at the level of the shell)

Answer (score 3):

This was happening to me too -
I realized I had defined my serverless configuration to package each lambda individually.
Which looks like this:

```
package:
  individually: true
```

Changing that to:

```
package:
  individually: false
```

worked for me.

(Of course if packaging your lambda functions individually is crucial for you, then you'll lose that, but for me it wasn't).